# Better Layout for Composing Question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, asking-questions, ios-app

This is minor, but *Body* should take up the rest of the page, not *Tags*. I know *Body* expands, but it's counter-intuitive. Putting *Tags* above *Body* solves it. I also believe there should be a divider line between fields.

### Old:

[image: old ask question interface]

### New Options:

[image: new ask question interface][image: alternate ask question interface]

Option on the right is an alternate to address @Hynes' concerns of workflow consistency.

I do still feel the lines are important though.

Comment: You're missing freehand drawing in your post.

Comment: ooh, i had that one coming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll see this in the next build, with lines and the body taking up most of the area.

[image]

Comment: Sweet! Any consideration to changing `Question body goes here...` to something else, like `Body` or `Question` or just blank?

Comment: Also there are a couple conflicts with the new paintbrush icon for markup. Should that be a *new* bug report?

Answer (score 0):

I disagree to a point. Tags could possibly be moved lower on the screen, but I wouldn't flip their order. That would differ from the workflow found in the "desktop version": enter a title, write your question and the add appropriate tags.

I'm not sure lines here would be useful either. The problem is that body and tags are similar in size initially and too close together. Separating tags more from the body area (maybe by pushing it to the bottom?) would help without needing to add visual clutter like lines.

Comment: I could support the solution of keeping tags on the bottom from the get-go. But I personally feel tags make more sense immediately after **title** *everywhere*, not just on mobile. But I'm sure I'm in the minority on that.

Comment: @mhlester -- I'm not advocating for the current workflow. Whatever my misgivings with it though, I'd rather it be consistent than changed here. Now if you want to go ahead and propose *that* feature-request, well I'd definitely be interested in that discussion. ;)