# For whom is the iOS app being designed?

Tags: discussion, ios-app

While testing the [iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220264/help-us-test-the-alpha-version-of-our-ios-app) - there is opportunity to give bug/feedback/feature requests, but I also don't want to waste time on asking for things that the app is simply designed to not do.

For example - the feed shows career ads and for a user of Stack Exchange that doesn't even have an account on Stack Overflow (or even computers), then those posts are a big drawback as they waste space on totally irrelevant content.

However, if this app is targeted at stack overflow users for the first release, then this request would be way lower priority or even something I wouldn't make.

Assuming this isn't a "DO ALL THE THINGS, FOR EVERYONE!! (AT ONCE)" effort, could you share with the community what you are designing the app to do and for whom?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a related question to this from when our Android alpha started last year: [What niche is the mobile app meant to fill?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193322/what-niche-is-the-mobile-app-meant-to-fill).

The mobile applications are made for all users. People who only use a single Stack Exchange site, people who use lots of Stack Exchange sites, people who have no idea what the sites are and simply download the applications because they're fans of different shades of blue stripes.

There's a lot of work done to get the applications onto that stage, but don't worry about being over eager about posting any bugs or feedback. Feedback is *critically* important to what we're trying to create and it's the reason why we're letting users in so early into the process of the application(s), so that we know if we're even on the right starting line.

If you have any feedback about an action you can do on the websites that you can't do in the applications or about mobile-exclusive things that would make experience better please tell us!

Comment: Excellent resource. I for one don't have experience using the site on Android, but chat on iOS is atrocious in both the mobile views and the full web views (IMO). Review queue and some moderation tools also are really poorly supported / buggy on iOS. I could see SE declining to address chat in this app for 1.0 and focus on fixing the other two implementations. At some point, focus is need to ship, but it's good to know hear that in the alpha - cast a wide net initially.

Answer (score 1):

To me the fact that feature requests are submitted through MSO lets this question answer itself, in that if you want a feature, you can request it, and the votes (in conjunction with time) give the developers a gauge of priority.

For instance, looking at my own feature requests,

> [Better Layout for Composing Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220628/better-layout-for-composing-question) (9 votes)

will likely be implemented before

> [Tapping Tags Loads Site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220826/tapping-tags-loads-site) (1 vote)

That said, it seems a waste to submit a request for *every missing feature*, but at the same time I don't think that's *detrimental* to the app's progress.